# How to avoid editText from overlapping recyclerView in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

The problem is when the soft keyboard appears, it overlaps the recyclerView. I want my soft keyboard just push recyclerview to the top, to be above the keyboard. I used windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" but the toolbar moves up when keyboard appears. I need my toolbar.

This is my chat layout

```
<RelativeLayout>
 
      <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/chat_toolbar"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
     

  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_below="@+id/chat_toolbar"
      android:layout_above="@+id/linear_type"
      android:id="@+id/chat_recycler"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>




  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linear_type"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

      <EditText
          android:id="@+id/edit_chat"/>
      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/post_chat"/>
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```